# Kotlin: как выдать свойство своего члена данных за своё свойство?

Tags: классы, kotlin, properties

Есть два класса. У первого класса есть открытое свойство. У второго класса есть закрытый член данных являющийся экземпляром первого класса и открытое свойство:

```
class A {
    var s = "test"
}

class B {
    private var a = A()
    public val prop = a.s
}
```

Хочется, чтобы свойство prop было ссылкой на свойство a.s. То есть если мы читаем prop, то получаем значение хранящееся в a.s. А если мы пишем в prop, то новое значение сохраняется в a.s. Если содержимое a.s меняется где-то в другом месте, то prop соответственно тоже должно обновиться.
Можно ли это сделать простым способом? Я попробовал сделать, как в этом коде `public val prop = a.s`, но это не работает - связи между свойствами не возникает.

Есть ли в Kotlin простой способо сделать такую ссылку на свойство другого класса?

Comment: Геттеры и сеттеры для этого и существуют. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геттер вам поможет.

```
class B {
    private var a = A()
    public val prop get() = a.s
}
```

Документация:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что вы имеете ввиду делегирование:

```
class A {
    var s = "test"
}

class B {
    private var a = A()
    public var prop by a::s
}
```